# replace links between <> with sed

Tags: linux, sed, replace

I have a file that contains text to keep and text to replace (links resulting from a conversion); I would like to delete everything between <>

```
texttobepreserved1
<text to be deleted, beginning with "https">, 
texttobepreserved2 
<text to be deleted, beginning with "https">, 
texttobepreserved3
```

i tried with this command

```
sed -i 's/https.*/ /g' *
```

but texttobepreserved2  is deleted ... and sometimes even texttobepreserved3 is deleted until a new line break
suggestions? thank you

Comment: Everything between `<` and `>`: `sed 's/<[^<>]*>//g' file > newfile` (see [demo](https://ideone.com/cn0RLR))

Comment: If it's HTML/XML, use a proper parser

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
sed 's/<[^<>]*>//g' file > newfile
```

*Details*:

- `<` - a `<` char
- `[^<>]*` - zero or more chars other than `<` and `>`
- `>` - a `>` char.

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/cn0RLR):

```bash
#!/bin/bash
s='texttobepreserved1
<text to be deleted, beginning with "https">, 
texttobepreserved2 
<text to be deleted, beginning with "https">, 
texttobepreserved3'
sed 's/<[^<>]*>//g' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
texttobepreserved1
, 
texttobepreserved2 
, 
texttobepreserved3
```